# mmc could not create the snap-in. CLSID: FX:{18ea3f92-d6aa-41d9-a205-2023400c8fbb} error

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, mmc

MMC Snap-in will not load most processes and throws an error on Windows 2008R2 x64. It gives the error:

> mmc could not create the snap-in. CLSID: FX:{18ea3f92-d6aa-41d9-a205-2023400c8fbb} when opening server manager.

It also gives similar errors opening the event viewer, etc. I think that the .NET Framework is messed up but I can't narrow down the exact cause. Has anyone else seen this issue? I have a dmp file of mmc.exe but haven't been able to get anything meaningful out of it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I ran into the same issue and tried everything I could find on the internet regarding this.  After working with Microsoft for 3 days we found the fix.  Please see below for all the steps that were completed, and finally what solved the issue.  This was for a Server 2008R2 machine:

## Symptoms

> MMC could not create the snap-in.  The snap-in might not have been installed correctly.
>
> Name: Server Manager
>
> CLSID: FX:{18ea3f92-d6aa-41d9-a205-2023400c8fbb}
>
> Name: Event Viewer
>
> clsid: fx: {b05566ad-fe9c-4363-be05-7a4cbb7cb510} Event Viewer
>
> Name: Task Scheduler
>
> clsid: fx: {c7b8fb06-bfe1-4c2e-9217-7a69a95bbac4} Task Scheduler
>
> Name: Windows Firewall with Advanced Security
>
> clsid: fx: {b05566ac-fe9c-4368-be02-7a4cbb7cbe11} Windows Firewall with Advanced Security

Server Information

> Microsoft Server 2008R2 SP1
>
> HP ProLiant DL380G6

## Resolution

- Replaced `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config` with known working file
- Replaced entire `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\` folder with known working folder
- Ran System Update Readiness Tool for Server 2008 – all reports came back with no error
- Ran `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\WFServicesReg.exe /r /b`
- `sfc /scannow` was ran, came back clean
- Ran [.NET Verifier](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2017/11/21/net-framework-setup-verification-tool-cleanup-tool-and-detection-sample-code-now-support-net-framework-4-7-1/) on all version of .NET, all came back verified successfully
- Reinstalled .NET 3.5 via CLI:

  ```
  DISM /online /disable-feature /FeatureName:NetFx3
  DISM /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:NetFx3
  ```
- Removed registry keys:

  HKLM\Software\Microsft\OLE\MachineAccessRestriction
  HKLM\Software\Microsft\OLE\MachineLaunchRestriction
- Restarted “Start DCOM Server Process Launcher” service
- Replaced files `dsadmin.dll` and `dssite.msc` located at `C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-d..mc-sitesandservices_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_a143f244c78549c1` with a good know version
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MMCSnapIns\FX{b05566ad-fe9c-4363-be05-7a4cbb7cb510}\RuntimeVersion`, changing value from `v2.0.40607` to `v2.0.50727`

### Final resolution from Microsoft:

- The Servicing stack of the Operating System was clean as reported by the Sfc output
- Uninstalling/Reinstlaling  Visual C++ 2005/2008/2010 with a reboot took out of the picture Visual C++ library components
- The .Net Policy had the correct value under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\Policy\v2.0` - `50727`=`50727-50727`
- Uninstalling McAfee didn’t help even after a reboot.
- The Components and Schema hive unloaded after a few reboots
- The IDNA trace that we gathered indicated that we fail due to a bad function pointer most probably returned by a .net component. After applying the Update https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2688730 and a reboot the issue went away which indicates we have a broken/damaged .net component on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winservermanager/thread/6e77f9d0-e86d-4a35-abed-504cf217fc96).  It sounds like a corrupted update.

Comment: Yeah I Saw that but the weird thing is all of my system scans pass with flying colors. I have another machine that works and it doesn't have any references to that update. I am guessing because i'm on 2008R2 and not just 2008.

Comment: Based on that and this: http://jaredheinrichs.com/mmc-error-18ea3f92-d6aa-41d9-a205-2023400c8fbb.html it seems that this is often caused by a problem with a .net installation (more specifically a corrupted machine.config).  In most cases, people seem to simply rebuild the machine; however, if that is out of the question (and you have some free time) would it be possible to uninstall and reinstall .net?

Comment: Well I think I figured out what is going on. Our application has a windows group that is assigned permissions on the GAC folders. When I delete the group the snap in breaks. The weird thing is that administrators still have access to the GAC according to the permissions but that doesn't seem to apply anymore when the group is deleted. If I go and remove the references to the group on the GAC security it also removes the administrators access. You are locked out of re-installing .NET since Server Manager does not open and its a part of the OS on Windows 2008R2.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue, but it worked just fine, when i removed .Net 3.5 from my system, and just by that removal everything got back to normal .. this looked to be a problem with .net itself, i have not tried to install 3.5 again when i will do that will update the thread

Comment: CLSID : FX: Snapins can not work without .NET, so you still have other version of .NET installed, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Look for the corrupted snapin and remove the key after backup

Example for Task scheduler

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MMC\SnapIns\FX:{c7b8fb06-bfe1-4c2e-9217-7a69a95bbac4}] and 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MMC\SnapIns\FX:{c7b8fb07-bfe1-4c2e-9217-7a69a95bbac4}]

Answer (score 0):

Per [Akira Umehara](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/akira%20umehara/?ws=usercard-mini)'s answer on [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/eb317c2f-ebf1-42fe-8fcc-a61a1246f5d9/mmc-could-not-create-the-snapin-clsid-fx18ea3f92d6aa41d9a2052023400c8fbb-error?forum=winserver2008appcompatabilityandcertification), another solution is:

1. Navigate to the following directory on the corrupt machine: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG`
2. Copy the `machine.config` file to desktop just in case before you go to 3rd step.
3. Rename `machine.config` to `machine.config.old` (in the original directory: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG`).
4. Reboot (not always required, but ensures a clean start).

NB: The above applies to x64 operating systems.  For x86, do the same only using the directory: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\`.

I get the impression this only works for OSes not yet upgraded to .net framework 4 was released; though have found nothing explicitly to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

## Noticing Issue and Initial Findings

I had the same issue on `Windows Server 2008 R2`; I believe caused by a failed `Windows Update` attempt; failing due to a full C drive.

- Freed up space on C drive
- Tried all techniques mentioned on here and [in this blog](http://clintboessen.blogspot.com/2011/02/fx813c1b01-6624-4922-9c6c-03c315646584.html), with no joy (mentioning as these may have partially resolved the issue).
- Noticed that the [.Net Verification Tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2017/11/21/net-framework-setup-verification-tool-cleanup-tool-and-detection-sample-code-now-support-net-framework-4-7-1/) crashed when run on .net versions =v4.
- Noticed that `c:\windows\assembly` was displaying sub-folders instead of the standard GAC view (potentially due to a missing [desktop.ini](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cumgranosalis/2005/10/02/that-annoying-cwindowsassembly-folder/), though I did not realise at the time)
- Noticed that some apps were reporting a missing dll (`Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop`).

## Steps to fix

- Ran Windows Explorer as Admin
- Copied the GAC (`c:\windows\assembly`) from a the VM from which this server had originally been cloned, ensuring missing files were created in the GAC, but existing content was left unimpacted (I generally wouldn't recommend this; but the server was not vital, and all other routes had been exhausted).  NB: The source VM included the missing `Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop` DLL.
- Rebooted

This resolved several issues:

- The GAC now displayed as expected
- The missing DLL issue was resolved (i.e. the DLL was there; and we no longer saw exceptions related to this DLL)
- The .Net Verifier ran for all versions of .net; and reported all as healthy.

However, the original issue (per question) remained.

- Reran the below commands to again remove and re-add the .net 3.5 feature:

  ```
  DISM /online /disable-feature /FeatureName:NetFx3
  DISM /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:NetFx3
  ```
- The disable command failed; but enable completed successfully
- The issue was resolved; presumably the enable-feature command somehow kicked something missed by the GAC copy into place...

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error a few minutes ago on one of five identically installed, and I just updated Windows Server 2008 R2 Terminal Servers and now it works again.

All I did was go to `File > Options` and then I deleted the about 460 KB of files stored in the user profile, confirmed the dialog, closed the MMC. After reopening, everything is working fine again.